# Copying files into HDFS Hadoop

Tags: bash, hadoop, hdfs, cloudera

I am currently working on a project for one of my lectures at the university. The task is to download a book from https://www.gutenberg.org/ and copy it into HDFS. I've tried using `put <localSrc> <dest>` but it didnt work at all.
This is how my code looks in Terminal at the moment:

```
[cloudera@quickstart ~]$ put <pg16328.txt> <documents>
```

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 30.05.2017: I haved used following link https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/quickstart_vms/5-10.html to install `Hadoop` and did not configure anything at all. Only thing I did was to absolve the tutorial `Getting started`.

Answer (score 0):

It should just be:

```
hdfs fs -copyFromLocal pg16328.txt /HDFS/path
```

I'm not familiar with the `put` command, but have you tried it without the `<>`s?

Comment: Thank you very much and how do I make HDFS open?

Comment: You can access hdfs through a range of `hdfs` commands, or `hadoop fs`. Applications like Hue will also give you a UI.

Comment: hdfs _dfs_ -copyFromLocal

Answer (score 0):

If you have successfully extracted and configured `Hadoop`, then

you should be in `hadoop-home` directory ( the location where you extracted and configured `hadoop`)

Then apply the following command

```
bin/hadoop dfs -put <local file location> <hdfs file location>
```

or

```
bin/hdfs dfs -put <local file location> <hdfs file location>
```

You can do the same with `-copyFromLocal` command too. Just replace `-put` with `-copyFromLocal` in above commands.

for example : 
 
Lets say you have `pg16328.txt` in your Desktop directory, then the above command would be

```
bin/hadoop dfs -put /home/cloudera/Desktop/pg16328.txt /user/hadoop/
```

where `/user/hadoop` is a directory in `hdfs`
If `/user/hadoop` directory doesn't exists then you can create it by

```
bin/hadoop dfs -mkdir -f /user/hadoop
```

You can look at the uploaded file using `webUI` (`namenodeIP:50070`) or by using command line as

```
bin/hadoop dfs -ls /user/hadoop/
```

Comment: I probably didnt install Hadoop properly since I can't find it in `home` directory.

Comment: Can you update the question with the summary of procedure you took to install and configure hadoop? so that we can help you more